# How can i obtain Value for specific key from this JSON string Android?

Tags: android, json, wcf, get

I have a result from the wcf service , which returns a JSON string like below,

```
[[{"Key":"Name","Value":"Profile"},{"Key":"Icon","Value":"Assets\/MenuIcons\/ProfileRegistration"}],[{"Key":"Name","Value":"CAF"},{"Key":"Icon","Value":"Assets\/MenuIcons\/CAF"}],[{"Key":"Name","Value":"STBTOOLS"},{"Key":"Icon","Value":"Assets\/MenuIcons\/STB Tools"}]]
```

from this how can i obtain Name and Icon as a Pair for particular one, There are three key value pairs. When i do like this, it gives an error as No  No value for Name;

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);      

for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray innerJsonArray = obj.getJSONArray(i);
    JSONObject jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
    String areaID = jsonObject.getString("Name");
    String Icon = jsonObject.getString("Icon");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Your json values are mapped in "Key" and "Value", not in "Name" or "Icon"
The left part is the key and right part is the value. You are trying to retrieve values using the values in the getString method.
You should do

```
jsonObject.getString("Key");
jsonObject.getString("Value");
```

instead of :-

```
jsonObject.getString("Name");
jsonObject.getString("Icon");
```

Your Json :-

```
[
[
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "Profile"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Icon",
        "Value": "Assets/MenuIcons/ProfileRegistration"
    }
],
[
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "CAF"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Icon",
        "Value": "Assets/MenuIcons/CAF"
    }
],
[
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "STBTOOLS"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Icon",
        "Value": "Assets/MenuIcons/STB Tools"
    }
]
```

]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i did the way as you mentioned but still am not getting the Value for the specific key

Comment: Please post your full code. I will look into it. You could debug it and find the error line

Comment: I have posted the code above, other part is that just calling the service and getting the result.

Comment: I'll run it.,did you try debugging the code in the above lines.

Comment: ya i did, i get the areaID as Name, and icon as Profile, what i actually want is, areaID as Profile and path for that ProfileIcon which is inside the value

Comment: dude, this is your json, i have posted the code to extract value from key. Please check my code below

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. I put your json in a folder named raw in res directory and here is the code and it is working  fine like i told you :-

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json);  
// Create a folder named "raw" and add a file named "json" and pasted your json code in it to test it .
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int ctr;
    try {
        ctr = inputStream.read();
        while (ctr != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(ctr);
            ctr = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.v("Text Data", byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
    try {
        String json = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
        System.out.println(json);
        JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(json);      

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray innerJsonArray = obj.getJSONArray(i);
            JSONObject jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String areaID = jsonObject.getString("Key");
            String Icon = jsonObject.getString("Value");
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```